# EOF Loop PHP output file

Tags: php, export

HI every one this is only my second post, but im really stuck and would appreciate any help, a big thanks in advance. I am working on zencart exporting data from the database to 2 csv files, file one is working perfect, but when i run file 2 i have a problem with the EOF loop, for some reason it displays the last product thousands of times as below and dosent end the loop,

```
ST,206,1,WIPAC 8" 4x4 100w Off-Road Driving Lamp Set Inc Grilles,0.0000,0
ST,387,0,Wolf Bench Grinder - WBG200/MD200F - Home - Tools - DIY,0.0000,0
ST,360,0,Wolfcraft TS 800 Adjustable Trolley - Home - Garden,0.0000,0
ST,116,0,WWE Ruthless Aggression 6 Pack - Wrestling Game - RARE - Retro,0.0000,0
ST,419,0,Zinc Ion XY Black Folding Scooter - Outdoors - Toy,0.0000,0
ST,220,0,Zoobles Mama & Zoobling Trinka and Tito & Tonia #306 Play Set,0.0000,0
ST,220,0,Zoobles Mama & Zoobling Trinka and Tito & Tonia #306 Play Set,0.0000,0
ST,220,0,Zoobles Mama & Zoobling Trinka and Tito & Tonia #306 Play Set,0.0000,0
ST,220,0,Zoobles Mama & Zoobling Trinka and Tito & Tonia #306 Play Set,0.0000,0
ST,220,0,Zoobles Mama & Zoobling Trinka and Tito & Tonia #306 Play Set,0.0000,0
ST,220,0,Zoobles Mama & Zoobling Trinka and Tito & Tonia #306 Play Set,0.0000,0
ST,220,0,Zoobles Mama & Zoobling Trinka and Tito & Tonia #306 Play Set,0.0000,0
ST,220,0,Zoobles Mama & Zoobling Trinka and Tito & Tonia #306 Play Set,0.0000,0
ST,220,0,Zoobles Mama & Zoobling Trinka and Tito & Tonia #306 Play Set,0.0000,0
ST,220,0,Zoobles Mama & Zoobling Trinka and Tito & Tonia #306 Play Set,0.0000,0
ST,220,0,Zoobles Mama & Zoobling Trinka and Tito & Tonia #306 Play Set,0.0000,0
```

the current code i am using is below (thanks to jon from post 1 whos got me this far :)

```
$products_cost =
"select p.products_id, pd.products_name, p.products_quantity, ".
  "p.products_cost, (p.products_quantity*p.products_cost) AS products_total_cost, ".
  "p.products_type ".
"from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p, " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd ".
"where p.products_id = pd.products_id and pd.language_id='" . $_SESSION['languages_id'] . "' ".
"order by (p.products_cost) DESC, p.products_cost desc, pd.products_name";



 $products_stock = $db->Execute($products_cost);



//Start Of Output for Stock File    

while(!$products_stock->EOF) {
$output = array();      
$output["tx_type"]='ST';        
$output["Stock_Code"]= $products_stock->fields['products_id'];
$output["Qty"]= $products_stock->fields['products_quantity'];
$output["Description"]= $products_stock->fields['products_name'];
$output["CostPriceEx"]= $products_stock->fields['products_cost'];
$output["TotalCostEx"]= $products_stock->fields['products_cost'] *  $products_stock->fields['products_quantity']; 

zen_sages_fwrite($output);
$products_stock->MoveNext();
}
$stimer = microtime_float();
```

I really do welcome any advice or guidance any one can give

Many thanks

Russell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo?

```
while(!$products_sock->EOF) {
                  ^---missing a T?
```

Comment: sorry that was a copy past error, it is while(!$products_stock->EOF) {

Comment: no idea. haven't got a clue what the db abstraction library you're using is or how it works.